# error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make an android plugin for unity and I have a simple method that shows a toast message:
In Unity:

```
    public static void ShowToastMessage(string message)
    {
        if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            string[] args = { message };
            string result = WDAndroid.Call<string>("showMessage", args);
            if (result != "success")
                print("Toast message error: " + result);
        }
        else
        {
            print("Toast message: " + message + " (Toast not supported on this platform)");
        }
    }
```

In android studio:

```
    public String showMessage(String message){
        String toReturn = "success";
        try {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } catch (Exception e){
            toReturn = e.getMessage();
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
```

And I get the following error:
`error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'`

I'm pretty sure my android jar is properly set up and no errors are given if I don't ask for a return value. I think the issue has something to do with the unity AndroidJavaObject class. The documentation on it I've found to be pretty sparse but I saw someone do something similar to what I did on https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidJARPlugins.html
(as shown in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J8ll.png)

Does anyone have experience doing what I'm trying to do who can help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Literally I walked away for an hour and came back and the error was gone *sigh*. If anyone has a better answer than this, feel free to chime in with exactly what was going on here, I'm curious to know